# How to break one line of text into multiple lines of equal character length

Tags: text, terminal, putty

Say I have 45 characters in a line in a text file, and I want to break them up into multiple lines, 10 characters each, what command should I use in putty? Also, if there are not enough characters at the end to make it 10, just leave it as it is.

ex:
12345678901234567890123456789012345

to

1234567890

1234567890

1234567890

12345

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `cut` command with the option `-c` to cut the string based on number of characters.

```
a=1
b=4
myText="longString"
echo $myText | cut -c $a-$b
```

This will output `long`. This will help you to achieve what to want to do. When you want to repeat this, update the variables `a and b`.